# Avada Wordpress Themes, Font Awesome not working with S3, Cloudfrount CDN Setup

Tags: wordpress, caching

We're using the Avada theme on Wordpress with WP Super Cache turned on, and all the correct settings regarding CDN in the wordpress backend. However the icomoon (font awesome?) fonts are not working, and only work when caching is turned off or if the cdn enabled is turned off. Other than that we just get the square where there should be twitter icons, facebook icons etc.

What we've tried...

- CORS settings on S3
- Open CORS settings in the nginx conf file
- Inspect network, and we see that the font files are loading from the CDN without error.
- Reviewed the css file, and see that it has a relative path, but since the font files are loading as confirmed through the Network tab on developer tools, figure that that is not the problem.

Here's the homepage where you can see it in action : https://www.bestwebfirms.com/

Comment: The link you posted appears to be using a Font Family of 'icomoon' and shows up correctly.

Comment: Yeah, didn't have a chance to post the answer that we found a few hours after posting the question.  But even better, what we did as a working solution was answered by someone else below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common problem is that you did not forward your headers from s3 to your cloudfront distribution.  To fix this...

1. Go to your Cloudfront distribution.
2. Click the Behaviors tab
3. Edit Your Behavior (should have an existing one if your Cloudfront is already working)
4. Look for "Forward Headers"
5. Choose "Whitelist" from the drop down.
6. Add "Origin" from the left side to the right and save.

[image: screen shot of whitelisted origin]

Comment: That's exactly what we did.  I'd just note that it takes a while to show up so you won't see the results instantly.  (Found the answer yesterday, but didn't have a chance to post it before today.  Thank you for the help though, it's a perfect match)